# Alternative to maven goal `eclipse:eclipse`

Tags: eclipse, maven

I was looking for information about `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and I realize that there are some obsolete goals [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/), one of them is `eclipse:eclipse`.

Is there any alternative to doing the same from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

This plugin is deprecated, there's no need to use it anymore. In fact, it will do more harm than good.
In short: `eclipse:eclipse` generates all eclipse files based on the `pom.xml`. This means that if you change the pom, you always need the run the goal again. With m2eclipse it is aware of changes in the pom and will update your project on the fly in most cases. I know that if you update the source/target, you need to run a Maven Update from the context menu explicitly.